# How to put an async into a Flutter Stream definition?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, stream, future

I'm creating my first Flutter app. I have data coming from Firebase RTDB that I collect through a Stream to create a ListView of records. The Stream is used by a StreamBuilder(stream: getPhotoStream(), builder: ...). Within the getPhotoStream() function, I need to use the data received (URL) to download a file (downloadFile() function) that is a Future/async. If I do that, I got an error with my return value becoming Stream<List<Future>> instead of Stream<List>. Then, if I change my function to Stream<List<Future>>, the problem propagates to the builder at execution time: 'List<Future>' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

```
Stream<List<Photo>> getPhotoStream()  {
// Read the photos of the ownerUID as a Stream, download the images
//
Photo photo;
File imageFile;

// Reference to the Photos Owner's node
final _photoStream = _ownerRef.child('/Photos').onValue;
final streamToPublish = _photoStream.map((event) {
  final photos = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value);
  final photoList = photos.entries.map((element) await {
    photo = Photo.fromRTDB(Map<String, dynamic>.from(element.value));
    photo.file = await downloadFile(photo.imageURL, photo.key);
    return photo;
  }).toList();
  return photoList;
});
return streamToPublish;
```

}
....

StreamBuilder(

```
    // Stream of photos from Firebase
      stream: DataBase(ownerUID: _ownerUID).getPhotoStream(),

      initialData: [],

      // Build a LisView with each photo data
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Prepare list of photos
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // Read the stream of photos
          privatePhotosList = snapshot.data as List<Photo>;   <== execution error
```

How can I do this ?
Could you please help ?

Comment: use `final streamToPublish = _photoStream.asyncMap(....`

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I will try it.